The less than sign (<) does not work in my django template

The less than sign (<) does not work in my django template, it either treats it as html or it just does not work even if i try to do something simple like {% if 2<5 %}, the greater than sign works fine though
I am using it for the paginator but its not working even for normal stuff as mentioned before
As evident from the image above the < shows up in red, it does not work even for a simple operation.
Here's the same code as text:
{% for page in nums %} {% if forloop.counter >= 2 %} {% if forloop.counter == ticket_page.number ⅝}
<li class="page-item active">a class="page-link" href="?page={{ forloop. counter }}">{{ forloop. counter }}</a></li>
{% elif forloop.counter <= ticket_page-paginator.num_pages %}
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ forloop.counter }}">{{forloop. counter }}</a></li>
{% endif %} {% endif %}{% endfor %}
<!-- Dealing with the Next Pages -->


"The same code as text" is not the same. There is a missing < in the first "a" in the text. But in the screenshot, it can be seen. I guess you missed it when you copy and paste(?) The problem is probably in the syntax. It might be in the above of this HTML code. If you use proper formatting, it would be easier to see the missing part.

There appears to be a typo at the end of the first line. Instead of {{ there is ⅝}. This might be causing your problem, if it's not just a copy-paste to SO issue.

The problem is not with the syntax because even if i try something so simple like if 2 < 5, the less than sign shows up in red and it does not work

Maybe there is a problem with your django template reader. But you can use less than or less equal as lt or le.
for example for lt you can use this tag like this:
{% if a|lt:b %}{% endif %}

Remember the template reader in django sometime does not work properly and you should restart the server first then see if it is work or not.
